Injective monotonic mapping from rationals $\mathbb Q^2$ to $\mathbb R$

Exercise: $f: \mathbb Q^2\to\mathbb R$. Where $\mathbb Q$ is the  set of rational
numbers.
$f$ is strictly increasing in both
arguments.
Can $f$ be one-to-one?

This question is related to many questions like: Nonexistence of an injective $C^1$ map between $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb R$. However, I don't assume continuity and I only need to embed $\mathbb Q^2$ not $\mathbb R^2$.
My try:
I am thinking about construction. Since $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb Q$ are usually considered similar, I will start with $f:\mathbb N^2\to \mathbb R$.
Define:
$f(x,y)=x-1/y$
This is clearly an injective map. However, I don't know how to turn this into a map from $\mathbb Q^2$.

Why do you use $Q$, which is usually used for the rationals, instead of $N$?  What is the difference between them?  Your $f$ is a fine answer, strictly increasing in both arguments, unless $0$ is in the naturals.  It is easy to fix if it is.

@RossMillikan Sorry for the typo. Q does mean rationals in this problem. I start working with $N$, though.

Yes, there is such a map. You can equip $\Bbb Q^2$ with the lexicographic order and then use this argument (in fact, that can give you an order-isomorphism between $\Bbb Q^2$ and $\Bbb Q$!)

Or $f(x, y) = x + y \sqrt{2}$...
